# Instafeed not returning squared photos

Tags: javascript, instafeedjs

Using [instafeed.js](https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js) for Instagram feeds. I was using resolution: 'standard_resolution' and also disabled the Non Square Media option from the instagram client to get all the pictures squares on 612x612, however, this has stopped working out of the sudden and don't know where the issue is coming from.

Comment: Same problem here, the images from instagram.com/<:accountName>/media are non squared now. Is there a blog posts from instagram to those changes?

Comment: I tried to find something in their developer's blog but didn't find anything nor anything related to a new release that has affected this

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found a good solution here : https://humaan.com/blog/bigger-square-thumbnails-from-the-instagram-api/.

If you’re crawling the API with a script, you can do something like this in PHP to alter the thumbnail (where $post is your Instagram post object):

```
$thumbnail = str_replace('s150x150/', 's320x320/', $post->images->thumbnail->url);
```

Alternatively if you’re using JavaScript, you can do something like this:

```
var thumbnail = post.images.thumbnail.url.replace('s150x150/', 's320x320/');
```

Comment: Is there a way to use something like this without making two requests for each image?

Comment: the thing is to call the "thumbnail" media because it is square and replace 's150x150/' in the url of the media by the resolution you want. For example I used the best resolution 's1080x1080/'